# Download a file via jquery and redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, redirect, download

I'd like to figure out a simple way using jQuery to trigger a download when a text link is clicked. Also, after click the user is redirected to success page. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's say you have a link to your download page

```
<a class="downloadLink" href="www.example.com/foo.pdf">Download</a>
```

In your Javascript:

```
$(".downloadLink").click(
    function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();

        //open download link in new page
        window.open( $(this).attr("href") );

        //redirect current page to success page
        window.location="www.example.com/success.html";
        window.focus();
    }
);
```

Comment: If The download link was a PDF this would mean the redirect would be the primary page and the PDF would become a second tab. Is there a way to reverse this, so they are taken to the PDF with a second tab being the redirect?

Comment: Seems like this stopped working on the last Chrome version...